# Trying to use jQuery to set select option in .net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, select

I have already tried all the suggestions I have found here for setting the select option including .val()  .attr() and .prop().  I simply must be doing something wrong.  The objective is to select an option of a select tag based upon an optional URL parm.  No matter what I do, it simply doesn't change the value of the list.

Please note that I am stuck using jQuery 1.4

**HTML Fragment:**

```
<select name="Widget91$Widget91$MetaTagList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'Widget91$Widget91$MetaTagList\',\'\')', 0)" id="WidgetTabHost_WidgetZone48_WidgetContainer91_Widget91_MetaTagList">
    <option selected="selected" value="">None</option>
    <option value="T-Code">T-Code</option>
    <option value="Job Role">Job Role</option>
    <option value="Functional Area">Functional Area</option>
    <option value="Sub Area">Sub Area</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript as coded:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    filter = getURLParameter("filter");
    if (filter != null) {
    jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val(filter);       
    }
});
```

**Javascript as served:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    filter = getURLParameter("filter");
    if (filter != null) {
            jQuery("#WidgetTabHost_WidgetZone48_WidgetContainer91_Widget91_MetaTagList").val(filter);   
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you verified getURLParameter is returning exactly what you are looking for? and not some encoded string? Also, if your using asp.net 4 and up, perhaps set ClientIDMode="Static" on your dropdown list, you can then clean up your ID selectors and just use "MetaTagList".

Comment: @Sushil - thats because you're comparing 'name' and 'id'...

Comment: since you are reading value of filter from url it may contain special character eg %20(for space)

Comment: The missing "<" was in jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val(filter); was an artifact of this editor.

Comment: I did originally put in an alert to confirm that the URL parm was what I expected.  Even hardcoding a value like `jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val("T-Code");` does not work either.  @Sushil  I also tried MetaTagList.UniqueID that returns the generated name object.  Not the problem.

Comment: Not sure how to insert line breaks but, I have unsuccessfully tried these permutations:  

`//  $ has a null value  remember this is 1.4
   
jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.UniqueID%>").val(filter).attr('selected',true);  

//jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val(filter).attr('selected',true);  


//jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.UniqueID%>").val("T-Code");  


//jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val("T-Code");    

//jQuery('#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>>option:eq(filter)').attr('selected', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to select the filter that is passed in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 filter = getURLParameter("filter");
 if (filter != null) {
 jQuery("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val(filter).attr('selected',true);       
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#<%=MetaTagList.ClientID%>").val(filter);
```